# Which SBT version should I install so as to package, assemble Spark 1.6 programmes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, bigdata, cloudera-cdh

I am using cloudera 5.13.0 version and spark 1.6.0. If I want to use sbt tool inside the cloudera vm which version of sbt/scala I have to install?

Comment: Was the answer of use to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version (1.2.3) of sbt in Cloudera. [Sbt link here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).

Comment: but which sbt version to be installed?

Comment: Install sbt 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Use 0.13.x for SBT is my advice. You can indicate that regardless of SBT installation. Has nothing to do with Cloudera by the way. Scala 2.10.